# Framework for developing Desktop-like web applications in browser

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, extjs

I want to develop desktop-like applications in the browser.

I have seen KendoUI, Twitter Bootstrap and Sencha ExtJs. Is there a better / more flexible / free of charge desktop-like Framework based on html5 / jquery?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: good lucking finding something better than ExtJS that is free. If there were, ExtJS wouldn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're about to jump in an ocean of MVC libraries. Backbone, Agility, Spine, Batman, Angular, Ember... You better search on Google about all of them, read about them, choose the right one and then ask again.